# URL wise cookie laravel

Tags: laravel, session, cookies, subdomain, multilingual

I've created a project which is live. Till now i'm managing language using sumdomain like **en.example.com**, **tr.example.com** and etc. So due to separate subdomain I've no problem in cookie management like **random user_id cookie**.

But now i want to manage language using url like **example.com/en** , **example.com/tr** and etc
now the problem is i don't want user_id of **example.com/en** get override with **example.com/tr** it should be separate as it is in subdomain case.

So is there any way to handle this? I've tried **SESSION_DOMAIN** things but don't know i'm right or not.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you could set the cookie path in `config/sessions.php` but the problem is that (i'm assuming) the locale is determined on a per request basis, making this impossible. An alternative would be to replace the `StartSession` middleware with your own custom one e.g.

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession;

class LocaleAwareStartSession extends StartSession {

    public function getSession(Request $request) {
         $locale = <determine locale here>;
         config([ 'session.cookie' => config('session.cookie').$locale ]);
         return parent::getSession();
    }
}
```

You then need to replace the middleware in your `Kernel.php` :

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            // ...
            LocaleAwareStartSession::class, // instead of StartSession::class
            // ...
        ],
```

This should set the session cookie name early enough to use a different cookie name for each locale. You can (typically) get the locale by using `$request->route()->parameter('locale')` assuming you defined a parameter called `locale` in the matched route.

Comment: i'm already using custom **Locale** middleware in which i'm setting **Config::set('session.domain', env('APP_HOST').$segment);** so can i set **session.cookie** in place of **session.domain** ?

Comment: As long as that middleware runs before the `StartSession` middleware it should work.

Comment: yeah i've added it on the top of all middlewares in kernel. Now facing another issue before testing your answer, prefix locale value is appearing in function parameters instead of actual one.
Laracast link https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/dynamic-prefix-value-appearing-in-function-parameter?page=1 @apokryfos

Comment: i used `config([ 'session.cookie' => config('session.cookie').$locale ]);` but i can see for different languages there is different cookies created like `cookie_prefix_en`,`cookie_prefix_fi` but for rest of the cookies which i have set using `Cookie::queue` and etc there's no prefix thats why it's get merged

Comment: Re: The prefix locale issue, your route should have 2 parameters, e.g. `function accept($locale, $request)` though `$locale` might be null. Cookies using `Cookie::queue` are unaffected by this and are also not related to the session. You manually have to set their name appropriately to not get conflicts